# Executing Task freezes GUI when running from event raised by other Task, but not from Button.Click

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I have some tasks in a separate project to execute stuff asynchronously.
It all works as expected for a fews months now:

- A "started"-event is raised at the beginning so the GUI can start a
  busy indicator.
- At the end (or when an exception occurs) an "Ended"-event is raised
  so the GUI can stop the busy indicator and handle stuff.

But a new requirement states that I have to read the version directly after the programming without any user interaction.

My first thought was to call `ReadVersion` from the "Ended"-event of the programming.
However, when doing so, the UI freezes.
The busyindicator hangs on the "programming"-state and the window cannot be moved until the version is read.
When calling `ReadVersion` from a button.Click does not freezes the GUI.

*ProjectLogic:*

```
protected void ProgramImage()
{
    this.OnProgrammingStarted(new EventArgs());
    this.taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(this.ProgramImageAsync)
                .ContinueWith(
                            t =>
                            {
                                if (t.IsFaulted)
                                {
                                    this.TaskExceptionHandlerProgramming(t);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    this.ProgramImageAsyncDone();
                                }
                            },
                            this.taskScheduler);
}


public void ReadVersion()
{
    this.OnVersionReadingStarted(new EventArgs());
    this.taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(ReadVersionAsync).ContinueWith(
        t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    this.TaskExceptionHandlerVersionReading(t);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.ReadVersionAsyncDone(t.Result);
                }
            },
                this.taskScheduler);
}
```

*GUI:*

```
private void OnProgrammingExecuted(object sender, WorkExecutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // Logging + messagebox
        this.BiProgramming.IsBusy = false;
        this.Restart();
        return;
    }

    if (!e.Success)
    {
        // Logging + messagebox
        this.BiProgramming.IsBusy = false; 
        this.Restart();
        return;
    }

    this.BiProgramming.IsBusy = false;  // Stops busyindicator

    BL.ReadVersion();  // Window freezes and busyIndicator stays visible.
}


private void BtnReadVersionClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BL.ReadVersion(); // works as expected
}
```

**EDIT**

`OnProgrammingExecuted`is the method that is executed when an event is raised from within `ProgramImageAsyncDone`.

The method `ProgramImage`is called from the UI-thread.
And if I'm not mistaken, this means that `TaskSheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`ensures that `ProgramImageAsyncDone`(or `TaskExceptionHandlerProgramming`) are run on the UI-thread.

The fact that it did not cause any issues before, strengthens my opinion.

The problem lies in the line I had to add: the call to `ReadVersion`.
After adding this line, the UI is freezing.
But calling this method from a button.Click does not freeze the UI.

Comment: where do you hide your 'busyindicator'? Is it in `this.BiProgramming.IsBusy = false;` by using WPF? If the busyindicator doesn't hide, is there any possibility that the problem may lie in that property setter? Besides, you are using `this.taskScheduler' as a filed. Is there any possibility that the filed is modified in another thread which may cause unpredictable problem?

Comment: Busyindicator setter poses no problems. As stated in the question, that line did not cause troubles before I added the `ReadVersion`call.

Comment: `this.taskScheduler` causing troubles was my initial thought too. The field is only modified in the 2 lines you see in the code. I have tried to remove the line where I set the tasksheduler again in `ReadVersion`but this made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching for a solution I came accross [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) and I've rewrote my code using `Task.Run` to see if this solved my problem.
Apparently it did.

Changed code:

```
protected void ProgramImage()
{
    this.OnProgrammingStarted(new EventArgs());
    this.taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Run(() => this.ProgramImageAsync()).ContinueWith(
                            t =>
                            {
                                if (t.IsFaulted)
                                {
                                    this.TaskExceptionHandlerProgramming(t);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    this.ProgramImageAsyncDone();
                                }
                            },
                            this.taskScheduler);
}


public void ReadVersion()
{
    this.OnVersionReadingStarted(new EventArgs());
    Task.Run(() => ReadVersionAsync()).ContinueWith(
        t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                this.TaskExceptionHandlerVersionReading(t);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ReadVersionAsyncDone(t.Result);
            }
        },
                this.taskScheduler);
}
```